# How to remove vuetify installed using vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I installed vuetify using the command `vue add vuetify`, but an error as below occurred because I didn't create the project using `vue create <project>`, instead, I used `vue init <template> <project>`.
[image]
Then, my project cannot run anymore. When I issued `npm start`, tons of errors occurred. The screenshot below is one of them:
[image]
Could someone teach me how to recover from these errors? Can I remove this plugin? 

Or did it just destroy my project and I have to create a new one and start from scratch again?
Thanks

Comment: I hope you find a solution bro. But, I just want to let you know that your name and project-name are still visible in the third line of the first screenshot :"D

Comment: :) I noticed after posting... It is OK, nothing biggy, but thank you

Comment: can't you just fo `npm uninstall veutify` and after that, search your project for all occurrences of `veutify` and change accordingly?

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` then `npm install --save vuetify sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge`, likely some files are missing yet needed to be updated

Comment: @balexandre After some struggling I made it... Thanks for the hints!

Comment: @powerseed glad to hear  now... write down in the answer what have you done so the next guy with the same problems, can do exactly that 

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
npm uninstall vue-cli-plugin-vuetify
```

removes veutify as a dependency

Cross verify in `package.json' file